# How to use header group with 2 different datasets in stimulesoft?

Tags: stimulsoft

I have a header group with one dataset in stimulesoft.Now I want to add another dataset with that header group.How to make a relation between two datasets and header group?

Answer (score 0):

Only one DataSource could be used with a Data Band.

The Header band is connected to a certain band.

So you could use a connection to access another Data Source.